# After upgrade eslint says NodeJS is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have upgraded `Eslint` from 7.7.0 to 7.10.0 and `@types/node` from 14.6.0 to 14.11.2. The application `tsconfig.json` defines `types: ["node"]` and typescript is version 4.0.3. Eslint is called with `eslint --env node,es2020`.

Before the upgrade Eslint never flagged any problem in my code. Now Eslint started complaining that `NodeJS` is not defined in the following code fragment:

```
private handleServerErrors(error: NodeJS.ErrnoException): void {
    if(error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
        . . .
```

I silence the Eslint error and the compilation succeeded. So seems a problem specific to eslint, not the code.

The same problem happens in another file for namespace `JQuery`, but I had not yet investigated.

Is there anything I'm missing? Need to add some import? What has changed in eslint/typescript/node?

Thanks for your help!
mario

Comment: Well, If I put all these undefined namespaces in the `globals` section of eslint.yaml the error goes away. But this seems too gross to be the right solution. Why eslint before has not complained?

Comment: I run into this problem recently, it's very wired.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `@typescript-eslint/parser@4` causes this problem.

Downgrade it to v3 `@typescript-eslint/parser@3` to solve the problem.

See: https://github.com/Chatie/eslint-config/issues/45